# calculate from api paypal charges for payRequest

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I would like to calculate the paypal charges for performing an adaptive payment. I can get the payKey by submitting a pay [request](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPayAPI). After that point and before proceeding any further with the transaction I would like to calculate the fees of paypal for every receiver in a chained [payment](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro). Paypal does provide the percentages it keeps according to the transaction, but ideally I would like to calculate that through the API rather than hard code it in my application.

Do you know which is the api call (if any)?